# Is my approach structure good?

Tags: php, security

The index file:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/run.php';

$_action = (isset($_GET['cmd']) && ctype_alnum($_GET['cmd'])) ? $_GET['cmd'] : 'index';

switch ($_action) {

    case 'index':
    case 'default':
    case 'home':
        include $con_dir . '/index.php';
    break;
    default:
        include $con_dir . '/404.php';

}
```

The `run.php` file:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'config.php';

$app_dir = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
$lib_dir = $app_dir . '/lib';
$con_dir = $app_dir . '/controllers';

require_once($app_dir . '/lib.php'); //Include libraries

//Database Connection
try {
  # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
unset($password);

//Smarty
$tpl = new Smarty();
$tpl->template_dir = $app_dir . '/Smarty/templates/';
$tpl->compile_dir  = $app_dir . '/Smarty/templates_c/';
$tpl->config_dir   = $app_dir . '/Smarty/configs/';
$tpl->cache_dir    = $app_dir . '/Smarty/cache/';
```

The `lib.php` file

```
<?php
require_once($lib_dir . '/Smarty/Smarty.class.php');
```

The `config.php` file

```
<?php
$hostname = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'engine';
```

I think I can improve  this by doing the `switch()` more dynamic, let's say it, would it be possible to have that the `?cmd=filename` would be appropriate, how would I do it? And how do I do it secure?

Else way what do you think about my basic structure, how should improve it? What would you change etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You code looks fine. One minor issue: in the `catch(PDOException $e)` branch maybe you want to

- log the error ([`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)),
- show a fancy static error page to the user (*"It's not your fault, we have logged the error and we're working on it."* or something like this.),
- and/or call `die()`.

---

About the dynamic switch: I would use a whitelist array which prohibit including other files which are not in the array.

```
$pages['index'] = 'index.php';
$pages['default'] = 'default.php';
$pages['home'] = 'home.php';
$page = '/404.php'
if (isset($pages[$action])) {
    $page = $pages[$action];
}

include $con_dir . '/' . $page;
```

Comment: Is it possible to automatically create a new log file if it doesn't exists "error_log($e->getMessage() . "\n", 3, $log_dir . "/database.log");"

Comment: If it was question, yes, it's possible :-)

Comment: Yeah, +1 for whitelisting pages instead of allowing any.  I know my server logs frequently get people trying to abuse dynamic includes.